# Update_By_Query not creating task

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

When running:

```
ubqResponse = ElasticClient.UpdateByQuery(u => u
                                .Type("entity")
                                .Index(IndexName)
                                .Query(q => ubqquery)
                                .WaitForCompletion(false)
                                .Slices(ubqslices)
                                .Script(script => script.Source(ubqscript).Params(ubqparams)));
```

I then attempt to get the task that should have been created by:

```
var currentTask = ubqResponse.Task;
var status = ElasticClient.GetTask(currentTask);
```

However ocasionally whenever I try to get the task I get the following error in code and in Kibana:

```
{
  "error": {
    "root_cause": [
      {
        "type": "resource_not_found_exception",
        "reason": "task [WKeOw_8eShy-Fvk6lFCWWA:6047942] isn't running and hasn't stored its results"
      }
    ],
    "type": "resource_not_found_exception",
    "reason": "task [WKeOw_8eShy-Fvk6lFCWWA:6047942] isn't running and hasn't stored its results"
  },
  "status": 404
}
```

When breakpointing and retrying the Update_By_Query with the same properties it works fine.

Comment: How long does the task normally take to complete?

Comment: It depends on the number of documents found by the query it can be anywhere between 1 and <2000. Smaller amounts are near instant, finished by the time I get the task. Larger ones can take a few minutes

Comment: And do you attempt to retrieve the task immediately after the `update_by_query` response returns? Also, How many nodes in the cluster?

Comment: Yep, I try to retrieve the task immediately if "isCompleted" is false, the thread sleeps for a bit and gets the status again until "isComplete" is true. Then it loads another update_by_query, the application will run thousands of these. There are 4 nodes running ES.

Comment: We recently ran into this same problem. Haven't been able to figure out how it happens. We've only seen it once so far. We used updateByQuery to initiate a task, ES responded with the task id, but all calls to retrieve the task fail. As far as I can tell, that's an ES bug.

Comment: I noticed that this occurred when hitting ES with consecutive small Update_By_Query requests, I haven't seen this problem since I started batching requests. So my original query used Term query, by changing it to TermsQuery I could make larger Update_By_Query requests less frequently.